# Boostrap control-label class causing checkbox to not be aligned with label in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my angular application,
I need the label and the checkbox in different columns. This causes the checkbox to not be aligned with the label(it is slightly higher up and not centered horizontally with the label text 'GROUP')

UPDATE: NOT SURE IF SOMETHING CHANGED WITH JSFIDDLE. IT USED TO SHOW SHOW THE UNALIGMENT BUT IS NO LONGER DOING IT

See here http://jsfiddle.net/LLvmxd0s/7/

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">GROUP</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="grp" class="pull-left" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">GROUP</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 control-label">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="grp" class="pull-left" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However if I add control-label class to the div which contains the checkbox then the label and checkbox align horizontally to each other nicely. This feels hacky to me though.

Is there a better way to fix this alignment issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it I added another class to the div that contained the checkbox and gave it the following css

```
<div class="col-sm-7 checkbox-align">
      <input type="checkbox"

.checkbox-align {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to bootstrap 2.3.1 CSS in your fiddle, but are using bootstrap 3.x gridsystem? Anyway, as all the [**doc examples**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) clears out, you must wrap a checkbox inside a `.checkbox` parent. Also you should wrap the `<div>` containing the checkbox inside the `<label>` element itself. I guess that is the reason for you trying to use the ugly `.pull-left`.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="grp" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" />GROUP
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="grp" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" />GROUP
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fjsnnh9g/**

Comment: This is very helpful information, however, I need the label text (in this example the word GROUP) in front the checkbox.